# Permission denied error during multiple update on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using multiple updates feature on Firebase where I have created a object which is updating multiple locations in the database at once. I have given write permissions to each of those locations individually. Here is an example of what I am trying to update on Firebase as part of multiple updates

```
{
  "alarms/298302f2-f95d-4200-b2ca-53dcf5706125/date": 1478141940167,
  "userInfos/-KGvMbo5MK-W5q4qgcF0/alarms/298302f2-f95d-4200-b2ca-53dcf5706125": 1478141940167,
  "userInfos/-KGvMIPwul2dUY181xLQ/backupForAlarms/298302f2-f95d-4200-b2ca-53dcf5706125": 1478141940167,
  "alarms/57656d1f-4c01-4807-93ea-44ab42791140/date": 1479979440107,
  "userInfos/-KGvMbo5MK-W5q4qgcF0/alarms/57656d1f-4c01-4807-93ea-44ab42791140": 1479979440107
}
```

Let's say `firebaseUpdateObj` contains the above object. I am using below line of code to perform the update

```
firebase.database().ref().update(firebaseUpdateObj)
```

I am seeing the following error on the console

```
FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied
```

I have given write permissions to the `alarms` and the `userInfos` branch in the rules file and I am able to write at both of these locations using `firebase.database().ref().child('alarms').child(alarmId).set(alarm)` and `firebase.database().ref().child('userInfos').child(uid).set(userInfo)`. But looks like when I am giving the update command like above, it's trying to check if I have write permission at location `/` which I obviously don't.

Is this expected behavior? I am able to run similar update command on the server side but there I have the server permissions, so I guess the rules don't come into picture there. I am using Firebase `3.3.0`.

Comment: You don't need to grant permission at the top-level of the update. Multi-location updates check the permission for each separate path and allow the update if *all* paths are writeable. If you can't get it to work, share the [minimum code+JSON+rules needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I see this problem intermittently on my mobile app using react native but I am not able to reproduce it using similar code that I can run in a browser that I can share. So, the problem may be something unrelated to firebase.

Comment: Hmmm... or it could be something related to the way authentication/refresh is handled in React Native.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I will keep an eye out for the error and try to share more data and also update to the latest version to weed out any already fixed bugs. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521503/why-validation-rules-behave-differently-only-with-ondisconnect-update