# Why validation rules behave differently (only) with onDisconnect update?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have made some tests with firebase and saw difference in rules validation between `onDisconnect().update()` and simple `update()` using `newData.parent()` in rules.

When I using `update()` it works. But with `onDisonnect().update()` I have PERMISSION_DENIED!

Database rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$id": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true,
            "a": { ".validate": true },
            "b": { ".validate": "newData.parent().child('a').val() == 'a'" },
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
const valid = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
};

function update(obj) {
  console.log('update', obj);
  return ref.update(obj);
}

function onDisconnectUpdate(obj) {
  console.log('onDisconnectUpdate', obj);
  return ref.onDisconnect().update(obj);
}

update(valid);
onDisconnectUpdate(valid);
```

[Full example code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNXGPa)

[image: See a screenshot here]

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Great question Douglaz. It took some time to dig up the (unfortunate) answer that I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

During an `onDisconnect()` operation, each property is treated as a separate write operation while we're validating the rules. That means that in your case the operation fails. While this is an unfortunate design, it is unlikely to change in the near future. For this reason I recommend using simpler write operations in `onDisconnect()` handlers.