# Firebase multi-path update - Permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, angularfire2

I have been trying to add rules to my Firebase database for a few days but an error keeps poping and I can't find what is wrong.

There is the error :

> FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied
>
> PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

I searched for solutions and found some related post ([Permission denied error during multiple update on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847602/permission-denied-error-during-multiple-update-on-firebase)). It seems that the displayed error is not right. I though I got that because I had no rights set on my root path ('/'), but according to this post, this is not a problem.

I tried to set my 3 'write' rules to 'true' and it works, so I guess the problem must be in my rules.

See below my code.

**Angular service:**

```
let event = {
    "title": "Title"
    "uid": "FZON4aEQgKNnRlHqMH7ZwynhTtp1"
}

let uid = this.authService.fbUser.uid;
let eventId = this.db.list('eventsData').push(undefined).key;

let updateObject = {};
updateObject[`eventData/${eventId}`] = event;
updateObject[`userEvents/${uid}/${eventId}`] = true;
updateObject[`eventGuests/${eventId}/${uid}`]= {
  attendance: 2 // and some other data
};

return this.db.object('/').update(updateObject);
```

**Data hierarchy:**

```
{
  "eventData" : {
    "-KptoNEw3MKRfacLnqa6" : { //Some data equal to 'event' object in above Angular service }
  },
  "eventGuests" : {
    "-KptoNEw3MKRfacLnqa6" : {
      "FZON4aEQgKNnRlHqMH7ZwynhTtp1" : { // Some data }
    }
  },
  "userEvents" : {
    "FZON4aEQgKNnRlHqMH7ZwynhTtp1" : {
      "-KptoNEw3MKRfacLnqa6" : true
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "FZON4aEQgKNnRlHqMH7ZwynhTtp1" : { //Some data }
  }
}
```

**Firebase rules :** (I removed '.read' rights to make the code cleaner as they are not part of the problem)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "eventData": {
      "$eventId": {
        // Event owner can update data
        // OLD > ".write": "auth.uid == data.child('uid').val()"
        // NEW
        ".write": "(newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) && (!data.exists() || data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
      }
    },
    "eventGuests": {
      "$eventId": {
        "$uid": {
          // Event owner can add someone to the event
          // Actual user can modify his attendance
            ".write": "(auth.uid == root.child('eventData').child($eventId).child('uid').val() ) || (auth.uid == $uid && data.exists() && newData.exists())"
        }
      }
    },
    "userEvents": {
      "$uid": {
        "$eventId": {
            // Event owner can add his event to someone's list
          ".write": "auth.uid == root.child('eventData').child($eventId).child('uid').val()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look !

**UPDATE :**

Since the correction of a bug by Frank, I ran some new tests.

I did the update not in a multi-path way, but one by one, by commenting the ones I did not want to run. In addition, I tried with static values.

```
let updateObject = {};
updateObject[`eventData/-Kpu9op4_s3jCetav6xn`]= {
    "title": "Title"
    "uid": "FZON4aEQgKNnRlHqMH7ZwynhTtp1"
};
return this.db.object('/').update(updateObject);
```

Then :

```
let updateObject = {};
updateObject[`userEvents/${uid}/-Kpu9op4_s3jCetav6xn`]= true;
return this.db.object('/').update(updateObject);
```

And :

```
let updateObject = {};
updateObject[`eventGuests/-Kpu9op4_s3jCetav6xn/${this.authService.fbUser.uid}`]= {
  attendance: 2 // and some other data
};
return this.db.object('/').update(updateObject);
```

The 3 of them worked.

But when I run the code using multi-path (3 at the same time), I still get the permission denied error.

Comment: Why do you have array brackets around each child: ``[`eventData/${key}`]``?

Comment: Also note that we have no idea what `event` is. Please make sure your question contains the [minimal, complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One easy way to ensure this is to use hard-coded values for everything.

Comment: About the brackets, it is a remnant from when I used an external object (myUpdateObject[`eventData/${key}`]=myData). Let me update all that !

Comment: I wrote a first mistake below. But there's really too much going on in these rules, which makes it hard to see the problem. Have a look at the link I shared earlier, which explains how to minimize the code needed.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521503/why-validation-rules-behave-differently-only-with-ondisconnect-update

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521503/why-validation-rules-behave-differently-only-with-ondisconnect-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a last test to confirm what I though.

This is how my rules looked like when it failed earlier :

> **eventGuests** : Write if current user is owner of the event OR if current user is the one being modified
>
> ".write": "(auth.uid == root.child('eventData').child($eventId).child('uid').val() ) || (auth.uid == $uid && data.exists() && newData.exists())"
>
> **userEvents** : Write if current user is owner of the event
>
> ".write": "auth.uid == root.child('eventData').child($eventId).child('uid').val()"

Now, if I use the following instead, that works :

> (**!root.child('eventData').child($eventId).exists() ||** auth.uid == root.child('eventData').child($eventId).child('uid').val())

It seems like data from the transaction is not accessible before the end of the transaction.

By calling the following in this exact order...

```
let updateObject = {};
updateObject[`eventData/${eventId}`] = event;
updateObject[`userEvents/${uid}/${eventId}`] = true;
updateObject[`eventGuests/${eventId}/${uid}`]= {
  attendance: 2 // and some other data
};
```

... I was expecting *eventData* to be persisted and to be accessible in *userEvents* and *eventGuests*. And then if an error occured, the system would have rolled back. But it looks like it is not working that way.

Can anyone confirm that pushed data inside a transaction is not accessible until the transaction is validated ?

Answer (score 1):

A first mistake seems in `/eventData/$event`:

```
".write": "auth.uid == data.child('uid').val()"
```

Since `data` is the existing data at the location, I'm pretty sure this rule will fail when there is no existing data.

More likely you want:

```
(newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) && 
(!data.exists() || data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)
```

Comment: You are right. This was part of the problem, but I still get the same error in the end. I will update my answer with the few new tests I ran and the results.